# Ошибка из-за большого количества запросов, instabot, python

Tags: python, instabot

Есть проблема в том что я посылаю слишком много запросов, хотя я просто хочу отправить одно сообщение, в чём проблема? Вот код:

```
from instabot import Bot

# Замените на свои данные
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

def main():
    bot = Bot()
    bot.login(username=username, password=password)

    bot.send_message('Привет', ['otveti2281'])


main()
```

Код ошибки:

```
2023-08-08 10:50:38,241 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2023-08-08 10:50:38,244 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2023-08-08 10:50:38,767 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2023-08-08 10:50:38,768 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429